# Using IEnumerable<T> and IQueryable<T> in a generic repository

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have read a number of posts regarding the implementation of a generic repository. I have also read a number of posts that explain the difference between exposing IEnumerable vs. IQueryable from my repository.

I would like the flexibility of having my data filtered in the database (rather than in memory  by the client) but want to avoid having to define a separate repository interface for all of my entities (and concrete classes that implement those interfaces).

So far my repository looks like this:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);

    void Add(T entity);
    void Attach(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
}
```

and an example of a concrete implementation is:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private DbContext _context;
    private DbSet<T> _entitySet;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _entitySet = _context.Set<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _entitySet;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return _entitySet.Where(where);
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        _entitySet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Attach(T entity)
    {
        _entitySet.Attach(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        _entitySet.Remove(entity);
    }
}
```

In this case my repository uses `DbContext` so what I would like to know is how this works with the generic interface:

1. `IQueryable<T>` derives from `IEnumerable<T>`. In My find method I am returning an `IQueryable<T>` object but the client only sees this as an `IEnumerable<T>`. Does this mean that if I carry out any subsequent queries on the `IEnumerable<T>` object it will actually perform the operations on the database and only return the *results* (because the object *is a* `IQueryable` in this case)? Or,
2. Only the `Where` clause that is passed into the `Find` method is executed on the database and any subsequent queries that are performed on the `IEnumerable<T>` object are performed on the client. Or,
3. Neither of these happen and I have totally misunderstood how `IEnumarable<T>`, `IQueryable<T>` and `Linq` works.

**Update:**

I am actually fairly surprised at the answers I have received in the comments. My original repository returned IQueryable and subsequent research led me to believe this was a bad thing to do (e.g. if my viewModel accepts a repository in its constructor it can call any query it wants which makes it is more difficult to test).

All solutions I have seen for this so far involve create entity specific repositories so that IQueryable is not exposed (The only difference I guess is that I am doing this in a generic way).

Comment: As far as I can tell, anything but `IQueryable<T>` will be done on memory. I would return `IQueryable<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`, you can always go from `IQueryable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` when you are done with filtering. And anyway when you do a To.List() or when you iterate the `IQueryable<T>` it automatically goes as `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are returning `IEnumerable<T>` all subsequent calls will be done in memory (locally).

One thing to keep in mind is that LINQ operates with a set of extension methods. There are extension methods for `IQueryable<T>` which support all of the necessary wiring to perform queries in locations other than locally, and extension methods for `IEnumerable<T>` that just work locally.

Note that which of these is selected is based on the compile time type, not the run time type. So an `IQueryable` that is cast to an `IEnumerable` will be treated as an `IEnumerable`. This is different than the way class normally work (thanks to polymorphism) however it allows the call site control over how to perform these operations.

An example of where this is useful is when you need to get all of the records in the table and then count them. There is no need to perform the count in SQL if you are going to get all the results anyway.

Comment: I suspected this was how things work. What is your opinion on my solution? Do you think this is a valid compromise (rather than exposing IQueryable directly or creating entity specific repositories)? My idea is to provide overloaded versions of the `Find` method to support common scenarios (such as paging). Any further filtering / srting would simply be carried out on the client.

Comment: I like the part with "*based on the compile time type...*", good explanation! @Benjamin: Why don't you want to return `IQueryable<T>`? In my opinion returning `IEnumerable<T>` is the worst solution at all: You still have deferred execution (the query isn't executed when your `Find` method is finished, but when you enumerate the returned `IEnumerable<T>`). If you enumerate after the context is already disposed you get an exception. If you add a `Where` clause to the returned `IEnumerable<T>` you have performance surprises. Either return `IQueryable<T>` or materialized results like `List<T>`.

Comment: @Slauma: I don't want to return `IQueryable` because it effectively exposes the data access layer and means that the query logic can leak into other areas of your code. I have also heard `IQueryable` is more difficult to test. Your comment regarding the execution of the query was well timed; I was actually thinking about this exact scenario and was about to post a comment asking about this.

Comment: @Benjamin: The entire design of `IQueryable` is to allow querying at arbitrary locations in your code. If you don't want that, you may want to avoid LINQ all together and use a different underwiring that exposes what you want.

Comment: If I enumerate my IEnumerable object to get my result set is the 'where' expression still evaluated by the database or is the whole query evaluated on the client (because at this stage I am working with IEnumerable)?

Comment: @Slauma - your comment regarding an exception being thrown if I enumerate the results after the context is disposed is true if I also return IQueryable. Your other comment regarding the performance is valid but that is really the point of my question (i.e. what is happening in my scenario).

Comment: @Benjamin: `IQueryable.Where` = database, `IEnumerable.Where` = client. It doesn't matter where it is enumerated, it matters where `Where` is.